sub-Gaussian Multi-armed Bandit
Consider a collection of random variables $(R_{a,\ell})_{a\in[A], \ell\in[T]\cup\{0\}}$, where $A, T\in\mathbb{N}$, and $R_a\in[0,1]$ almost surely. Define
$$\widehat{\mu}_a^t:=\frac{1}{N_a^t}\left(R_{a,0}+\sum_{\ell=1}^{t-1} \mathbf{1}\left\{A_\ell=a\right\} R_{a,\ell}\right), \qquad N_a^t:= 1 +\sum_{\ell=1}^{t-1}\mathbf{1}\{A_\ell=a\},$$
where $(A_\ell)_{\ell\in[T]}$ is a sequence of actions and each action $A_t$ can be thought of as a random variable measurable with respect to $\sigma((R_{a,\ell})_{a\in[A], \ell\in[t]\cup\{0\}}))$. Finally, let $\mu_a:=\mathbb{E}[R_{a,\ell}]$.
Lemma 6.2 in this book shows that for all $t\in[T], a\in[A]$ we have that with probability at least $1-\delta$, $\delta\in(0,1)$
$$\left|\widehat{\mu}_a^t-\mu_a\right| \leq 2 \sqrt{\frac{\ln (AT / \delta)}{N_a^t}}.$$
The proof relies on the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality for bounded martingale difference sequences (Theorem A.5 of the same book). (I think there is a factor of 2 missing in the denominator of the upper bound, so they could have gotten a tighter bound). However, Theorem A.5 is more general, as it holds for sub-Gaussian martingale difference sequences (mds). As such, I started wondering about how to generalize the same argument presented in Lemma 6.2 for $(R_{a,\ell}-\mu_a)\overset{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{sG}(\sigma)$.
The new proof is practically identical to the previous one with one difference: I need to show that the summands of the mds are indeed sub-Gaussian. The mds is constructed as follows: $W_{a,\ell} = \mathbb{1}\{A_\ell=a\}(R_{a,\ell}-\mu_a)$ with filtration $\mathcal{F}^t:=\sigma((R_{a,\ell})_{a\in[A], \ell\in[t]\cup\{0\}}))$. Now, note that conditionally on $\mathcal{F}^{t-1}$, $A_t$ is deterministic. Therefore, $W_{a,t}\mid \mathcal{F}^{t-1}$ is either 0 almost surely (when $\{A_t\neq a\}$) or $W_{a,t} \sim \mathsf{sG}(\sigma)$ (when $\{A_t=a\}$). How can I formally conclude from here using Theorem A.5? Note that $\sigma>0$ in the definition of sub-Gaussian random variables.
An alternative I thought about was defining the collection of random variables as $(R_{a,\ell})_{a\in[A], \ell\in[T]\cup\{0\}}$, where $A, T\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\ell$ representing the $\ell$-th time action $a$ is played, rather than the round. This way
$$\widehat{\mu}_a^t:=\frac{1}{N_a^t}\left(R_{a,0}+\sum_{\ell=1}^{N_a^t} R_{a,\ell}\right), $$
where the $R_{a,\ell}$ are now dependent on each other via the random index $\ell$. With this equivalent notation, I find no problems extending Lemma 6.2 to sub-Gaussian random variables, but I'd like to understand what I get wrong with the previous notation (which I prefer and would keep using).
Any help is much appreciated, thank you for your time!
